# Purpose of using one loss function and metric another one in Tensorflow/Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm new to Deep Learning and I saw this for the first time. Having MAE as loss function and MSE to metric. What is the purpose of this and what is gained?

```
(loss=tf.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError(), metrics=[tf.losses.MeanSquaredError()])
```

Comment: This is not mixing loss functions, there is still a single loss (the MAE).

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy So why do we use the MAE as loss function and MSE as metric?

Answer (score 1):

In some cases it is useful to have a loss function different from the metric you are going to evaluate.

Consider the case in which you want to denoise an image, that is you design a network that takes as input a noise image and outputs its clean version. Here, your metric might be the Peak-Signal-to-Noise Ratio (PSNR) or some sort of structural similarity (SSIM) between your output and the ground truth clean image. However, during training, you might consider different loss function, such as L1 (MAE), L2 (MSE) or even a Perceptual Loss, such as the VGG loss, because these have been proved to lead to better results than directly optimizing for PSNR or SSIM.